# Zend Framework Loading a Controller Helper from another Controller Directory

Tags: php, zend-framework

Alright, I know this is a bit localized, as I'm sure not many break out of traditional Zend Framework logic. But. This is a case where I have one main piece of software developed on ZF, and in it 3 different levels of platform.

So I have your stock folder structure of Zend Framework, then in it 2 additional sub folders that act as layers on top of the main structure. These sub folders have "layouts" "views" "controllers" and respectively "helpers" "scripts", etc.. so. With that due to how this was laid out I have run into a bit of a Jam, where I need to access a helper that is stored in one sub section from another sub section.

Normally you would access the helper like

```
$this->_helper->enrollHelper->isCreationDriven();
```

But, the controller I need to call this helper from is in another controller directory. Note I didn't build this app initially I am just helping enhance features and continue its growth. Anyway.  The above line wont work for me in this case as the controller I want to call the helper from is outside of that directory in another like directory.

With that, My question is. Does anyone know a means I can call the helper in a similar fashion from this other directory? Or do I end up doing whats likely the obvious choice and just make a mirror copy of that helper in the other controllers directory where I want to call it from initially, my hope is there is a means as I want to avoid duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

During Bootstrap, you can register the second directory with the plugin broker using `Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath($path, $prefix)`.